# How do I prevent Out of Memory errors with large Stream data?

Tags: java

I am dealing with input streams of unknown size that I need to serialize to a byte[] for fail-safe behavior.

I have this code right now based on IOUtils, but with 5-50 diffrent threads possibly running this, I don't know how reliable it is.

```
try(final ByteArrayOutputStream output= new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
long free_memory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 5;
final byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
long count = 0;
int n = 0;
while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, n);
    count += n;
    free_memory -= n;
    if (free_memory < DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) {
        free_memory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        if (free_memory < (DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE * 10)) {
            throw new IOException("JVM is low on Memory.");
        }
    free_memory = free_memory / 5;
    }
}
output.flush();
return output.toByteArray();
}
```

I want to catch an OOM error before it is a problem and kills the thread, and I don't want to save the stream as a file. Is there a better way of making sure you don't use too much memory?

(I'm using Java 8)

Comment: What is `output` and what is point of `temp`?

Comment: @Andreas They are the same thing, just used the wrong name. fixed (The catch is just in a wrapper function)

Comment: By not reading huge datastructures into memory but processing them as a stream.

Comment: *FYI:* A try-with-resources variable is implicitly `final`. No need to declare it so. See JLS [§14.20.3. try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3): *A variable declared in a resource specification is implicitly declared `final` if it is not explicitly declared `final`.*

Comment: Unrelated: read about Java naming conventions._ is only for constants.

Comment: Not sure if it would work but you could try to catch OOM and suppress references to the large object so that it can get collected when exiting the method?

Comment: @M.leRutte unfortunately, the stream gets destroyed long before processing is finished (read by many processes). I need a local, stable, serializable, copy.

Comment: Is holding it _in memory_ stable and serialized?

Comment: @Tezra and what you do in case if you are not able to process all data from input stream? I mean, can your app survive this without any loss?

Comment: @Dario If parsing a stream takes up too much memory, I want the app to drop that message and notify the user immediately that the message could not be accepted. I just want to be sure that if I run out of memory, that won't kill the services running. (At least give me a chance to fix it by dropping the outputstream)

Comment: @M.leRutte It needs to be serializable so that it can be placed into a queue after it is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too answer your question, given the fact that multiple threads are running the same code, this is a very unreliable way.

The code asks the system how many memory is available with `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`, which is a value that is obsolete the instant it returns, as other threads will have consumed more memory in the meantime. The corresponding I/O exception that should be thrown in case some not so obvious threshold of remaining memory is thrown might or might not be executed, but whether it is is totally not important.

The capturing of the data is done inside a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which will increase (and copy) its buffer each time the end is reached. It is not controlled by the 'how much memory is there' check, so again, multiple threads will be resizing their buffer at the same time, any of which can fail.

The most fail safe manner is storing the data on a disk, thus making a copy. If the data comes from an outside streaming source you can use 
     [`Files.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)). If what you get is a file, you can use the other variant of [`copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), which *I think* delegates it to the OS.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question... I know my current solution is bad, but I don't know any other way to effectively do this. I just want IOUtils.toByteArray, but with fail-safes encase the stream size exceeds my JVM memory space.

Comment: You need to copy the input stream to a persistent storage, such as a disk, not into a very limited and volatile storage such as memory. That is the only way. There is _no_ fail safe manner to read a stream into memory. You can't go back in a stream and re-read the data, not without buffering.